# Set an AutoMapper convention to not merge ICollection properties

Tags: c#, automapper

Say I have a domain:

```
public class EmbeddedInBar
{
    public string Name { get; get; }
    public ICollection<int> ListOfInts { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> ListOfInts { get; set; }
    public EmbeddedInBar Embedded { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two existing Bars:

```
var destination = new Bar
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Destination",
    ListOfInts = new List<int>( 1,2,3 },
    Embedded = new EmbeddedInBar
    {
        Name = "DestinationEmbedded",
        ListOfInts = new List<int>( 4,5 }
    }
};

var source = new Bar
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Source",
    ListOfInts = new List<int>( 6,7,8 },
    Embedded = new EmbeddedInBar
    {
        Name = "SourceEmbedded",
        ListOfInts = new List<int>( 9,10 }
    }   
};
```

If I do a map

```
Mapper.Initialize(conf =>
{
    conf.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>()
        .ForMember(b => b.Id, opts => opts.Ignore());
});

destination = Mapper.Instance.Map(source, destination);
```

I end up with the enumerable properties being merged:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Source",
    ListOfInts: [ 1,2,3,6,7,8 ]
    Embedded: {
        Name: "SourceEmbedded",
        ListOfInts: [ 9,10 ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set up a convention in AutoMapper (rather than specific 'ForMember' statements, assume at compile time I don't know the property names / expressions)
that discards the destination ICollection values and overwrites them with the source values? So I end up with:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Source",
    ListOfInts: [ 6,7,8 ]
    Embedded: {
        Name: "SourceEmbedded",
        ListOfInts: [ 9,10 ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `AutoMapper` are you using? Version `4.2.1` is working as you described - it does not merge the collections. Take a look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J4ZSnx. Aren't you missing something in your description?

Comment: @kiziu `5.1.1` (latest at time of writing) which I can't get to load in dotnetfiddle

Comment: @kiziu Which I've just tested in LINQPad using the code from the fiddle you kindly put together and it works, no merging of collections. OK I've obviously simplified the example too far from my full code will add bits in until I work our where I broke it...

Comment: @kiziu Ah ha! spotted the difference I have **ICollection<int>** not _IEnumerable<int>_. With _ICollection<int>_ on _Bar_ and AutoMapper `5.1.1` it gets merged as edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using AutoMapper filtering : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#global-propertyfield-filtering

For your example you can use following:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(expression =>
        {
            expression.ShouldMapProperty = info => !(
                info.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                info.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

            expression.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>();
            expression.CreateMap<EmbeddedInBar, EmbeddedInBar>();
        });

        Mapper.Map(source, destination);
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I didn't understood you at first. I found a solution for your question. You can use Automapper custom type converters:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

The whole solution will look something like this:

Create collection type converter:

```
class CollectionTypeConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<ICollection<T>, ICollection<T>>
{
    public ICollection<T> Convert(ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Include it to mapper initialization:

```
Mapper.Initialize(expression =>
        {
            expression.CreateMap(typeof(ICollection<>), typeof(ICollection<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(CollectionTypeConverter<>));

            expression.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>();
            expression.CreateMap<EmbeddedInBar, EmbeddedInBar>();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderS but this ignores the source values and keeps the destination values. You end up with [1,2,3] and [4,5] in the collections not the desired source values [6,7,8] and [9,10]

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood your question at first. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found may have some unforeseen results - I don't have enough experience with `AutoMapper` to think of everything beforehand, so please use it carefully. On the face it, it shouldn't affect anything else then what is described in your question.

`AutoMapper` has a functionality called `Mappers`, stored in static collection `AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.Mappers`. Classes inside are able to alter the way objects are mapped. By default, collection contains quite a big set of different mappers ([see source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v5.1.1/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/MapperRegistry.cs#L8)), amongst which `CollectionMapper` might be found ([see source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v5.1.1/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/CollectionMapper.cs#L156)). This mapper is able to add items from source collection to destination collection, if it's not read-only. What you can do is to remove it from the collection of mappers by running this code before you initialize your mapper:

```
    var collectionMapper = MapperRegistry.Mappers.OfType<CollectionMapper>().Single();
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Remove(collectionMapper);
```

Removing `CollectionMapper` will not remove the functionality of mapping collections, this will be handled by second mapper called `EnumerableMapper` ([see source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v5.1.1/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/EnumerableMapper.cs#L9)). Difference between them is visible in the [line 26](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v5.1.1/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/EnumerableMapper.cs#L26) - this mapper does not use the destination property when mapping - it creates a new collection, which is filled with items from source collection.

I tested this locally with `AutoMapper 5.1.1` and classes you provided. Result is as you wanted.

Comment: This is cracking kiziu and works, both yours and @AlexanderS.'s did I just felt the ITypeConverter method more conventional to AutoMappers CreateMap API - thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidMcMinn, it works, but only when `ICollection<T>` is used. Try for yourself - use `List<T>` instead, you will see a mapping exception: `Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.CollectionTypeConverter<System.Int32> to type 'AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>,System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>>.`. Be careful while using it, because it will break mapping of `List`s.